# Angular DOMsanitizer URLs in a JSON file

Tags: angular, url, dom

I have a JSON with several of this data example below:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "title": "The Pink Tail Fly",
  "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/FnTWLxS-lGQ",
  "episode": "2",
  "season": "1",
  "likes": "26000",
  "source": "YouTube"
}
```

I would like to use the URL in my Angular project, but Angular won't let me unless I DOMsanitizer them. How can I sanitize the URL when they are part of an object with other key-value pairs?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check this post. It is exactly what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845834/domsanitizer-doesnt-parse-text-to-html/68847290#68847290

Answer (score 1):

We can write some helper functions/lambda that should handle what you need, like this:

```
import { Component, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly jsonData = {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "The Pink Tail Fly",
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/FnTWLxS-lGQ",
    "episode": "2",
    "season": "1",
    "likes": "26000",
    "source": "YouTube",
    "video_source_url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxYYYzzz-lGQ"
  };

  sanitizeField<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T, fieldName: K): string {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, data[fieldName]);
  }

  // just a helper lambda, scoped to the 'url' field
  urlFieldSanitizer = (data: any) => this.sanitizeField(data, 'url');

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    const saneURL = this.sanitizeField(this.jsonData, 'video_source_url'); // here you also have IntelliSense support

    const anotherSaneURL = this.urlFieldSanitizer(this.jsonData); // this is equivalent to this.sanitizeField(this.jsonData, 'url');
  }
}
```

---

If for some reason you don't want or need to actually sanitize the URLs, you can just bypass the security check with a new method like the one below:

```
  import { Component, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
  import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

  ...

  trustField<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T, fieldName: K): SafeResourceUrl {
     return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(data[fieldName] as unknown as string);
  }

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    const trustedURL = this.trustField(this.jsonData, 'url');
  }
```

Comment: thanks for responding to this question.  I have not implemented this yet but I think it will work fine.  Thanks